# How can I include data text files in a jar using Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build

In my src folder there is another folder called data which contains files data1.txt and data2.txt. The application loads a graph from these files in the initialization, so I want to include these files in my final jar. I use Ant to produce the jar file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example from http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html :

```
  <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/app.jar">
    <fileset dir="${build}/classes"/>
    <fileset dir="${src}/resources"/>
  </jar>
```

So basically you would want to include the data-files in the same way as "resources" are included above.

From the documentation of the `<jar>` task:

> It is possible to refine the set of files that are being jarred. This can be done with the includes, includesfile, excludes, excludesfile and defaultexcludes attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files to your classes directory, where they will be included into the jar.

```
enter code here

<target name="copyHibernateXml">
    <copy todir="classes">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/${sourceDir}" includes="*.xml,*.csv"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```