# read jar file variables from a configuration file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a java program which uses an external jar file. The jar file has some variables(IP addresses) that needs to be read from a configuration file.

How to I create one such configuration file? How to do I read it in jar? 
[For now, I have hard-coded the needed variables data in the jar file. But I want to change it as and when I like, so changing in the configuration file is easier and I need not export(or re-compile) my jar file always]

To be more clear:

I have two java files: A.java, B.java.
"A.java" is to be exported as a jar file and used by "B.java".

Now, I have to read some data(settings, IP addresses) within A.java. All these sort of data have to kept in a separate file and should be read into A.java. After enabling this, A.java will be exported as a jar file and used by B.java.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Is the external JAR in the classpath of your "java program"?

Comment: question is not clear....! "how to do I read in in jar" "jar has some variables", etc...

Comment: A recent related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704631/can-you-store-data-inside-a-jar

Comment: A faced a similar problem ... but I am trying to read from the code also present in the same jar... there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209107/read-a-file-kept-in-a-jar-from-java-code-also-present-in-same-jar was helpful

Comment: @kAdithyan: question made more precise.. pls have a look.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways.  If the jar is part of your classpath, then use [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

It this is from plain jar some where, use [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html)